# Manually logging out a user, after a site update in Django

Tags: python, django, authentication, logout

I have a website, which will be frequently updated. Sometimes changes happen to User specific models and are linked to sessions.

After I update my site, I want the user to log out and log back in. So I would log out the user right then. If he logs back in, he will see the latest updates to the site.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could just reset your session table. This would logout every user. Of course, depending on what your doing with sessions, it could have other implications (like emptying a shopping cart, for example).

```
python manage.py reset sessions
```

Or in raw SQL:

```
DELETE FROM django_sessions
```

Comment: for some it might be easier to just log into a database manager (phpPgAdmin, phpMyAdmin, etc), and just empty the `django_sessions` table. It has the same effect.

Answer (score -1):

See this: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#how-to-log-a-user-out

That seems to cover it.

Comment: Hello Lott, this is the normal logout, which can be called on demand. But what I wanted is a different one. Automatic logout of all users(ofcourse keeping in mind defrex suggestion on shopping carts) upon a site update.